# Can I solder camera cables to a breakout board?

Tags: usb, soldering, camera, gpu

I've got an NVIDIA Jetson with 4 cameras connected to it via USB 3.0. The GPU does not have enough ports so I am relying on a USB hub to connect everything. I've experimented with several hubs and they tend to be bulky and the rover that I have them on tends to jitter a lot and so the USB plugs lose connection every now and then which can only be fixed if I reboot the system. I've experimented with glue and other things but this proves problematic as sometimes I need to cycle the plugs (plus it's just not an ideal solution).

Some solutions I came up with:

1. I'm thinking of creating a breakout PCB, stripping the camera cables down and soldering them all to this board and then soldering their equivalent cables on the other side to the board which then plugs into the NVIDIA's USB port.
2. Another solution might be to terminate all of the camera cables to a high quality bulkhead which then breaks out to various cables on the other side.
3. I break down the USB hub enclosure, desolder the female side of the connector and just solder straight to the pads.

Does anyone have any advice or concerns on this?

On thing that came to my mind was the unshielded portions of the cable might not be healthy for the camera signals (including the traces on the board), but this would be very small sections, though at least this way I would be certain that there's no plug disconnection issues.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I think only solution 3 has a small chance, but how will you cycle the no longer existing plugs?

Answer (score 1):

2 is the least compliant. Don't do that one.

What does 1 actually get you? Seems like you still have all the connectors but some pcb in the middle?

3 isn't standards compliant AFAIK. You reduce your problem to a single wire (hub to host) assuming that your soldering is good. If you keep the wires equal and tightly twisted then it should be fine as a one off project then maybe it would work. Usb 3.0 SS is more finicky than 2.0. Maybe test with extension cables first before you try with the actual cables.